# UIImageView loses quality after panning?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

This is a very, very subtle effect, but I am noticing that my UIImageView images become slightly blurry after being dragged around.

I'm simply using a UIPanGestureRecognizer to move it around the screen, and affecting the alpha when it is being moved (making it lighter when dragging around for UI effect).

Does anyone have clues as to why it would lose some image quality and get a little blurry?

```
-(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    self.alpha = 0.7;
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.superview];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.superview];

    //make the sprite slide on release
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        self.alpha = 1.0;
        CGPoint velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:self.superview];
        CGFloat magnitude = sqrtf((velocity.x * velocity.x) + (velocity.y * velocity.y));
        CGFloat slideMult = magnitude/200;

        float slideFactor = 0.01 *slideMult; //increase for more slide
        CGPoint finalPoint = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + (velocity.x *slideFactor), recognizer.view.center.y + (velocity.y * slideFactor));

        finalPoint.x = MIN(MAX(finalPoint.x, 0), self.superview.bounds.size.width);
        finalPoint.y = MIN(MAX(finalPoint.y, 0), self.superview.bounds.size.height);

        [UIView animateWithDuration:slideFactor*2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{recognizer.view.center = finalPoint;}
                         completion:nil];
```

*Edit: I believe it has something to do with the sliding effect when the state ends.

Comment: Please post the code you are using when moving the image.

Answer (score 3):

If your imageView.frame.origin is on a fraction like (6.66666, 7.55555) the image may blur. This is just simple pixel alignment.

In your panning code, use CGRectIntegral to align to integers like so:

```
panningImageView.frame = CGRectIntegral(panningImageView.frame);
```

There are other options, such as roundf(), ceilf() and floorf() if you need different rounding behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll keep that in mind. However in my instance, I think I've narrowed it down to the sliding effect when the gesture ends.