# Button Image Quality Collection View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view where each cell contains 7 buttons, (created via code not storyboard).

They are sharp initially, however if I scroll up / down a few times the quality decreases.

The sharpness is restored when I change views and return.

Any ideas ?

Addit:

I am making the buttons like this, within a loop (can be 1 to 7 buttons)

```
- (UICollectionViewCell*) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"patientCell";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Patient *aPt = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    PatientCVCell *ptCell = (PatientCVCell *) cell;
    ptCell.ptName.text = aPt.name;
    ptCell.ptRoom.text = aPt.room;
    ptCell.ptRx.text = aPt.diagnosis;

    int xPos = 20;
    NSArray *daysForRx = aPt.ofList.listDays;
    // loop through to add button for each day of Rx

    for (int i = 0; i < [daysForRx count]; i++) {
        // get the treatment day that == postition in array

        for (Treatment *t in aPt.patientRx) {
            if (t.day == daysForRx[i]) {
                //NSLog(@"%i", xPos);
                StatusButton *testButton = [StatusButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                testButton.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, 110, 28, 28);
                testButton.btnTreatment = t;
                // match status of the RX to the correct button

                if ([t.status intValue] == NotSeen) {
                    [testButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toSee"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    testButton.linkNumber = NotSeen;
                }
                else if ([t.status intValue] == SeenNotCharted) {
                    [testButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"seenNotCharted"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    testButton.linkNumber = SeenNotCharted;
                }
                else if ([t.status intValue] == SeenCharted) {
                    [testButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"seenCharted"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    testButton.linkNumber = SeenCharted;
                }
                else if ([t.status intValue] == NotSeeing) {
                    [testButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notSeeing"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    testButton.linkNumber = NotSeeing;
                }
                else if ([t.status intValue] == NotSeeingDC) {
                    [testButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notSeeingDischarged"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    testButton.linkNumber = NotSeeingDC;
                }
                [testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [cell addSubview:testButton];
                xPos = xPos + 36;
            }
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

The image is correct size so no need to scale the image.

Occurs in simulator and on device.

---

After looking more closely, the inside of the images are sharp! So this issue has to do with the transparency for my circle shape of a button within a square button!

Comment: Please share code, otherwise its difficult to understand whats going on...

Comment: Check your `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate` methods and your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass for code that could lead to "blurriness". I would first look at all CGRect calculations. Make sure your images are aligned to actual pixel. You have to floorf(), roundf() or ceilf() to the next pixel (which means 1 pt on non-retina and 0.5 pt on retina). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844092/uiimageview-loses-quality-after-panning

Comment: tried and no luck, I think its a memory issue. When I scroll my memory usage slowly increases - even when I have a blank UICollectiveViewCell and no content. The issue seems to be in the cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Added to apple forum so i can add pictures. https://devforums.apple.com/thread/202521

Comment: You should have posted the code that you put to apples dev forum here. I did that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dequeuing a cell, then you add your buttons to the dequeued cell.

Those buttons never get removed. When you scroll up and down cells that go off screen are put on the dequeue queue. At this time they still have the buttons, then they are dequeued and you add more buttons. You have many buttons above each other, and that's why it looks blurry and your memory footprint gets bigger.

I would add the buttons from inside the cell. Save them in a array so you can remove them later. Then I would add a method to set the number of buttons you'll need. Like this:

```
// header
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *buttons;

// implementation
- (void)setNumberOfButtons:(NSInteger)numberOfButtons withTarget:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector {
    // remove existing buttons from view
    [self.buttons makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    // "save" existing buttons in a reuse queue so you don't have to alloc init them again
    NSMutableArray *reuseQueue = self.buttons;

    self.buttons = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numberOfButtons];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++) {
        UIButton *button = [reuseQueue lastObject];
        if (button) {
            [reuseQueue removeLastObject];
        }
        else {
            button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            // you should always use the same target and selector for all your cells. otherwise this won't work. 
            [button addTarget:target action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
        [self.buttons addObject:button];
        button.frame = ....
        // don't set up images or titles. you'll do this from the collectionView dataSource method
    }
}
```

you would then set the number of buttons in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` and configure each button according to your needs. something along those lines:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell*) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Cell *cell = ... dequeue ...
    Object *object = ... get from your backend ...
    /* configure your cell */
    if ([cell.buttons count] != object.numberOfItems) {
        // no need to remove and add buttons if the item count stays the same
        [cell setNumberOfButtons:object.numberOfItems withTarget:self selector:@selector(buttonPressed:)];
    }
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [object.numberOfItems count]; i++) {
        UIButton *button = cell.buttons[i];
        [button setImage:... forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

And the action would look like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    UICollectionView *collectionView;
    CGPoint buttonOriginInCollectionView = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:collectionView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:buttonOriginInCollectionView];
    NSAssert(indexPath, @"can't calculate indexPath");
    Cell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell) {
        NSInteger pressedButtonIndex = [cell.buttons indexOfObject:sender];
        if (pressedButtonIndex != NSNotFound) {
            // do something
        }
    }
    else {
        // cell is offscreen?! why?
    }
}
```

pretty straight forward. Get the indexPath, get the collectionViewCell, check which index the pressed button has

Comment: I would not need to do this if I added the buttons to IB directly ? I did this as a test and my allocations are still increasing just with scrolling up and down.